# Xpath, retrieving node value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I get this return value from Sharepoint... which I have just included the first part of the xml snippet...

```
<Result ID=\"1,New\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
<ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode><ID /><z:row ows_ID=\"9\"
```

It populates a XmlNode node object.

How using xPath can I get the value of ows_id ?

My code so far...

XmlNode results = list.UpdateListItems("MySharePointList", batch);

**Update**

So far I have this  : results.FirstChild.ChildNodes[2].Attributes["ows_ID"].Value

But I am not sure how reliable it is, can anyone improve on it?

Comment: That's not exactly xpath but merely DOM access.
Using a traditional xpath library would leave you with a list of nodes matching your query - try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its necessarily an *improvement*, but it might be more readable, though more verbose:

```
/*[local-name() = 'Result']/*[local-name() = 'row']/@ows_ID
```

There is probably more to the fragment you posted so this XPath query might need a fixup when used against the actual xml result.

The function, local-name(), lets you ignore namespaces, which can be both a boon and a curse. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you start from root:

/Result/z:row/@ows_ID

also you can improve search if exists multiple Result:

/Result[@ID='1,New']/z:row/@ows_ID

Answer (score 0):

The specific xpath calls depend on what library you use (e.g. libxml xpath implementation).
But the generic xpath statement would be:

```
"//z:row[@ows_ID='9']"
```

This will select all z:row nodes with an attribute ows_ID of value 9.
You can modify this query to match all z:row nodes or only those with a specific attribute.

For details look here: [W3Schools XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: I don't know the value of ows_id, thats what I want to retrieve. Any ideas on how to get that value as a string? I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="Result/b:row/@ows_ID"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="Result/b:row[@ows_ID = '9']"/>
```

Depending on what value you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make sure the z namespace prefix is declared correctly - that's implementation dependent. [Here's how you do it in Java's XPath implementation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html).

Then to select the value of the ows_ID attribute, you need to navigate to the element itself, then use @ows_ID to get the value.